# use image as link, hide/replace it when clicked at the same time

Tags: html, css, image, href, swap

I'm trying to use an image as a link, while swapping it with another image when clicked at the same time. (Basically want to make it look like a button is pressed, once the user clicks on it). Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<a class="button" id="nonpressed" href="..."><img src="images/nonpressed.png"/></a>
<a class="button" id="pressed" href="..."><img src="images/pressed.png"/></a>
```

**CSS**

```
.button {
position: absolute;
top: 540px;
left: 90px;
}

#nonpressed {
z-index: 2;
}

#nonpressed:active {
visibility: hidden;
}

#pressed {
z-index: 1;
}
```

The problem is that once I get to hide *#nonpressed* the link isn't working anymore. I tried hide/show and replace with jQuery too but it didn't really help either.. (well maybe I just messed up, since I'm only getting started with web design--). Any ideas on how I could make this work? Thank you very much!!

Comment: Unless your buttons are really fancy, I would advise against using images.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I have to use a very specific "do not press" button for my project, so creating/styling one from scratch with divs would be much much more complicated in this case... :,)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to change the entire link if you just want to change the image. It's very easy with using background-image property. So it's CSS only solution ...

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/);
  background-size: 100px 100px;
}

.button:active {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/2/);
}
```

```html
<a class="button" href="#"></a>
```

Either way if you want to hide/show the entire (`img`) link try with `display: none;` and `display: block;`. Then you will also need to add a `wrapper` cause if you click on the item and hide it then it's gone and nothing will know that you still click on it cause you hide it ... does that makes sense? Like so it works:

```css
.button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

#nonpressed,
#pressed:active {
  display: none;
}

.wrap:active #nonpressed {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<a class="button" id="nonpressed" href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/2/"/></a>
<a class="button" id="pressed" href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/"/></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you so much! I didn't really mind which way it would be done, so I used the first code; I'm keeping the second for future reference too, it's surely going to be useful soon as well! Thanks again!!

Comment: @noot glad it helped. I would always recommend the first way, for many reasons! The second way is just in case you for whatever reason you should do like so to show how it could work .. happy coding!